# exporting .svg images to .pdf in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, html, images, pdf

I have a set of .svg images that I need to export to pdf by using org-mode. Even though I can see the images inside emacs, I cannot export them to .pdf. On the other hand, if I export my .org file to html I can see all the .svg files.

I installed librsvg2 packages for ubuntu 18.04. What could problem be?

B.R.

Comment: the svg file has to be rendered. I remember threads about it but I can't remember. I recommend you try search the [orgmode mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode) and/or to join the list.

Comment: I think I understand what is happening. When I export to .pdf. Org-mode ignores the file extension part that is .svg hence it does not produce the image. @manandearth do you know any work around about this?